# How to insert a table from an MS Access database based on the username into a DataGridView?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I'm making a program in which the user can view their product orders. Their product orders are stored in an Access Database table called "tblOrders". "tblOrders" fields are ProductName, Quantity, PriceEach, TotalPricePerLine, OrderTotalPrice, and Username.

I would like the user to only see their orders, instead of the entire table. To do this I want the orders shown to be based on the user's username.

Here is my code so far:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb    
Public Class Form1  
     provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="       
     dataFile = Application.StartupPath & "\SAC1 Database.mdb"
     connString = provider & dataFile
     Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
     Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
     Dim ds As DataSet
     Dim tables As DataTableCollection
     Dim source1 As New BindingSource

Private Sub btnDisplayDataGrid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayDataGrid.Click
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [tblOrders]", MyConn)
        da.Fill(ds, "items")
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        DataGridOrders.DataSource = view
End Sub
```

However, this does not do exactly what I want it to. It displays the WHOLE table into the DataGridView. I want it to be based on the user's Username.

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're talking about filtering data, which you do with your SQL code. Do some research on how to write a query with a filter.

Comment: @jmcilhinney What exactly does a query do? How does it choose to display data based on the username from the table? Thanks.

Comment: We're not here to teach you the basics of programming. If you don't know what a query does and how to filter the data it retrieves then you just haven't tried to learn. You need to learn these fundamentals for yourself and try to apply them first. If you try and you can't get it to work then you would post a question here but we're not here so that you don't have to try.

Comment: @jmcilhinney are there any YouTube videos on it or any articles you could send a link about? I can’t seem to find anything anywhere. Thanks heaps, I’ll try my best to try and figure it out, I’m just a programming newbie looking for advice and help. Thank you.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Even an example would be great. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: SQL is an entire language unto itself.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]...because you havent

Answer (score 0):

Your sql should filter by username. The ? is a placeholder that is replaced by the parameter value: Change the GetMyUserName function as needed to get the user name that your application needs

OleDbDataAdapter generates some extra commands that you don't need for insert, delete, update actions. If you only need to read data, a OleDbCommand best fit your needs

```
Private Sub btnDisplayDataGrid_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisplayDataGrid.Click
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim username As string = GetMyUserName()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * from [tblOrders] where username = ?", MyConn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", username)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dt.Load(reader)
        source1.DataSource = dt
        DataGridOrders.DataSource = dt
End Sub

Private Function GetMyUserName() As string
    GetMyUserName = "myname"
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, have been away. I receive an error that states: "dt has been is used before being assigned a value". When clicking btnDisplayDataGrid, it crashes due to this. Does Source1 need to be replaced with anything? Also does the "?" need to be replaced by a parameter like @username? If so where do I connect the parameter to the getmyusername? Thank you so much.

Comment: I have edited my post, creating the DataTable in the declaring line. The ? is a placeholder for parameters. `@name` syntax is for Sql Server. As you are using OleDb, I have used OleDb syntax. But if your database is sql server you can (it's better choice) use sql server syntax

Comment: still unsure of what to put in the ?, so I put username. When clicking btnDisplayDataGrid I receive an error highlight "cmd.Parameters.Add(username)" stating: System.InvalidCastException: 'The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.'
How do I fix this, thanks again.

Comment: changed the parameter assigment in the post. Try now

Comment: Thanks again, receive an error highlighting: "reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()" that reads: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.'"

Comment: I assumed that MyConn was declared and initialized outside the method. You need to assign it a connection string and open it

Comment: ohhh I see, will do that in the morning and report back to you. Thank you, I made a silly mistake